# Ajax prasererror on localhost but working fine on live server

Tags: jquery, localhost

As the title says, my code works on live server but not on localhost.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/php/get.php',
    data: {zipCode:zip },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        //console.log(data);
        if(data == ''){
            var output="<h1 style='text-align:center;'>No Search Results</h1>";
            document.getElementById("itemholder").innerHTML=output;
        }else{
            show(data);
        }
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
        alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown); 
    }
});
```

The error output i am getting is

```
Status: parsererror

Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

This json parser is fairly new to me, so what would be the difference between localhost and live server causing this to fail?

////Edit////

I checked php info and JSON is enabled.
Also my database is all letters and numbers with a few of these symbols

```
: - _ .
```

Any more ideas?

Comment: Unrelated, doesn't this look much nicer: **$("#itemholder").html(output);**

Comment: I guess your local server isn't configured like the live server and the response contains additional data like html tags, that could come from a php notice/warning/error

Comment: Server responds with something different than JSON.

Comment: My php script returns json_encode($items); and there is no html tags in the database. Why would localhost treat this differently? Also how might I fix localhost to respond correctly? @pmandell yes it does, I just have not gone back and cleaned up the code yet.